# Convert BufferedImage to aws...rekognition.model.Image

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, bufferedimage, amazon-rekognition

I'm playing around with the Amazon Rekognition. I found a really [nice/easy library](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture) to take an image from my webcam which works like this:

```
BufferedImage bufImg = webcam.getImage();
```

I'm then trying to convert this `BufferedImage` to a `com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.Image` , which is what must be submitted to the Rekognition library. This is what I'm doing:

```
byte[] imgBytes = ((DataBufferByte) bufImg.getData().getDataBuffer()).getData();
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(imgBytes);
return new Image().withBytes(byteBuffer);
```

However when I try and do some API call to Rekognition with the `Image`, I get an Exception:

```
com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.InvalidImageFormatException: Invalid image encoding (Service: AmazonRekognition; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidImageFormatException; Request ID: X)
```

The [docs](http://docs) state that the Java SDK will automatically base64 encode the bytes. In case, something weird was happening, I tried base64 encoding the bytes before converting:

```
imgBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(imgBytes);
```

However, the same Exception ensues.

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried encoding the image to a JPG (Rekognition supports PNG or JPG formats) and it solved the problem.

```
BufferedImage bufImg = webcam.getImage();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bufImg, "jpg", baos);
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(baos.toByteArray());
return new Image().withBytes(byteBuffer);
```